# How to print an ASCII file that is 80 characters wide

Tags: pdf, printing, font, text

I have a file that is 80 characters wide. I am using OS X.  The problem that I have is when I open the file and try to print it in TextEdit, the lines wrap before the 80 character mark. I'd like the file presented in the same way printed as it is in the file. So, my question is this;

How do I print an 80 character wide ASCII file (and preferably specifying margins) such at the font will be fixed-width and sized appropriately to fill the entire page while still retaining the position of original line breaks and not additional wrapping. If the resultant file is a PDF or other format convertible to PDF that would be fine. If anybody could answer this question I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Textedit, make the file plaintext by going to the Format menu, and selecting the Make Plain Text command. This will use a fixed-width font and remove any other characters.

Next, Select `Page Setup...` from the File menu, then select `Paper Size:` and go to `Manage Custom Sizes`.

Create a Paper Size of 8.5 wide x 11 high, set the top, bottom, left & right margins to zero, then save the custom size by clicking the "+" button.

Go to the File menu > `Export as PDF`.

On the `Export as PDF` click on `show details` and uncheck the box that says `Rewrap contents to fit page`

Just tested this and it works for me!

Comment: I appreciate you responding, IconDaemon.  Unfortunately this did not work for me, it is still adding line breaks and not fitting 80 columns on one line.

Comment: It worked for me +1. @dps Could you upload a sample of the file and provide a link?

Comment: certainly, thank you both for your help.  https://gist.github.com/dsulli99/1cb9ebc455e0307d367deb4d6a495689

Comment: Textedit does not wrap the lines for me even in rtf mode.

Comment: It doesn't wrap the lines until I print it, even with 0 margins on 8.5x11

Comment: @dps, I downloaded your file and followed IconDaemon's directions from "Next, Select ..." as it was already plain text. The first time I exported to PDF it didn't work however I went back into "Page Setup..." and checked the settings and clicked OK to the settings again and then exported it to PDF again. The second time it worked.  When I used my own text file that was  80 character wide it worked the first time, so not sure what to make of it. Try confirming the settings again clicking OK again and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @dps, Okay... I figured out why (I think)... The TextEdit windows needs to be opened wider then the width of the text otherwise it wrapped. You'll have to play around a bit to find the sweet spot for the window width differential.

Comment: @user3439894 I had to actually uncheck the box that says `Rewrap contents to fit page` under the `show details` for the `Export to PDF` dialogue.  This seems to have worked, although the text is not centered (I would like it to be centered on the page).  I might have to use ghostscript or some more advanced text processing to get this the way I want it.  I appreciate your help @Mark and @user3439894.

Comment: Sure thing @IconDaemon 